# Add a calculated column to a Laravel Eloquent model and sort and/or filter on that column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm trying to code a query in Laravel/Eloquent that contains a calculated column.  The result set of that query needs to be sorted and/or filtered based on the calculated column.  The query is;

```
  SELECT member_names.id,
         member_names.member_id,
         member_names.membership_owner,
         Concat(member_names.last_name, " ", suffixes.description, ", ", surnames.description, " ", member_names.first_name, " ") as name,
         vip_codes.description,
         membership_types.description,
         membership_statuses.description
    FROM member_names
         LEFT JOIN members ON member_names.member_id = members.id
         LEFT JOIN surnames ON member_names.surname_id = surnames.id
         LEFT JOIN suffixes ON member_names.suffix_id = suffixes.id
         LEFT JOIN vip_codes ON member_names.vip_code_id = vip_codes.id
         LEFT JOIN membership_types ON members.membership_type_id = membership_types.id
         LEFT JOIN membership_statuses ON members.membership_status_id = membership_statuses.id
   WHERE member_names.membership_owner=1
ORDER BY name;
```

The calculated column is `name` and is calculated with the following;

```
Concat(member_names.last_name, " ", suffixes.description, ", ", surnames.description, " ", member_names.first_name, " ") as name
```

I believe this one is unique as it needs to reach out to the suffixes and surnames tables to calculate the column.  The other answers I've seen so far stay within the table.

I have models for member_names, members, surnames, suffixes, vip_codes, membership_types and membership_statuses.  They are all connected properly.  In other words, I can issue a simple query with

`MemberName::->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->orderBy(first_name, 'asc')->where('membership_owner', 1)->paginate(10)`

and down stream resolve additional table look ups in the controller or view with no problem.  My problem is I need the data that comprises the name upstream in the query.

My alternative is to turn this into a view in the database but I'd rather not clutter up the database.

Thank you to Marcin Nabiałek for the advise.  Worked like a charm.  The final version of the query, for us newbies, is as follows;

```
$name = 'Concat(member_names.last_name, " ", suffixes.description, ", ", surnames.description, " ", member_names.first_name, " ")';

$memberNames = MemberName::selectRaw("member_names.*, {$name} as name")
    ->leftJoin('members', 'member_names.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
    ->leftJoin('surnames', 'member_names.surname_id', '=', 'surnames.id')
    ->leftJoin('suffixes', 'member_names.suffix_id', '=', 'suffixes.id')
    ->orderByRaw($name)
    ->paginate(10);
```

The LEFT JOINs for vip_codes, membership_types, and membership_statuses weren't needed until further downstream in the view so they could be left out at this point with Eloquent resolving it as it's supposed to.

For more information see the Laravel manual at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already they query written as Eloquent and you need to add this single column, you can do something like this:

```
$name = 'Concat(member_names.last_name, " ", suffixes.description, ", ", surnames.description, " ", member_names.first_name, " ")';

MemberName::selectRaw("member_names.*, {$name} as name") 
   // here you put joins and other code you need
->orderByRaw($name)
->paginate(10)
```

Comment: Thank you to Marcin Nabiałek for the advise. Worked like a charm.